# what are the commenting system most suited for rails application.. In particular what are the steps to integrate disqus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, disqus

I tried using the javascript code the 'disqus' website gave me.. but to no avail..
Could someone give some steps to do the same.
Sorry, am a newbie to rails.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /**
    * var disqus_identifier; [Optional but recommended: Define a unique identifier (e.g. post id or slug) for this thread]
    */
   var disqus_developer = 1;
   var disqus_shortname = 'npoint0';
   var disqus_identifier = <%= @deal.id %>;
  (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = 'http://npoint0.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript=microreviewsorg">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

Comment: Disqus isn't a rails problem; it's just an HTML problem. What Can you post what problems you're having with disqus?

Comment: Hi, I was able to integrate disqus but once i logout (as the user who has registered the domain on disqus), the entire disqus box vanishes...  the code snippet used is now provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

i would use the [disqus gem](https://github.com/norman/disqus)